# Synchronize database files with the database - PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

First forgive me for my English. It is a little bad. Second forgive my ignorance, i'm newiest in postgres

I'm having trouble when I try to up a backup database on another database. I need to dump the database just to get one table, but I only have the files that was in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/base/`

Here what I try:
I create a database named "test" with OID 227763 so I put the files of the old database to this new database with another OID. I fix the folder and files permissions, but when I log into "test" and run `select * from pg_tables;` the tables does not appears to me. And when I try to create the table on PhpPgAdmin, I got

> ERROR: relation already exists

I'm trying to do this because I need to know which of this files is the table that i want. I will log into database and run `SELECT oid,* from pg_class;` to get the OID.

I found the old OID database in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/global/pg_database`

If anyone can help me, I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to backup and restore an entire database or a single table. It sounds like you need to be using pgDump instead of working on individual files. A file level copy is likely to corrupt your database if not in backup mode and if not copying the entire thing + archive logs.

If you MUST copy it by files, make sure the database is shut down for maximum safety.

For me, if I had one table to backup, I'd use pg_dump

```
pg_dump -U {user-name} {source_db} -f {dumpfilename.sql}
```

you can use the -t flag to list a single table if you like.

Comment: It's a good information, but what i'm trying to do is another thing. I don't have the database in my server, i only have the table files (not in .sql extension)
Ex: root@cloud [/var/lib/pgsql/data/base/17067]# ls
0730  1255    226267  226306  226348  2600  2618  2665  2687
0732  1259    226269  226308  226350  2601  2619  2666  2688

I need to know which of this files is the table i'm looking for. And how i put this table on the base.

Comment: and if possible I do it, even with data loss.